# Why am I receiving an error when trying to retrieve message templates using the WhatsApp Business Management API in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, whatsapp, whatsapi

Hey There Developers I am Trying to Integrate What's App Cloud Api from Meta for Developers Console and I am trying to Retrieve The Messages Templates using the api's .Reading it from there [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/business-management-api/message-templates/) i had created the api to retrive the templates but it shows me this error

```
"error": {
        "message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (message_templates) on node type (WhatsAppBusinessPhoneNumber)",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 100,
        "fbtrace_id": "AHUox6aJYuhq3S7NnNDSE03"
    }
```

It would be a great help if you can help me solve this problem I have been Researching on the same for over a week now .....Thank You in advance

I am looking this api to retrieve all my available templates on the developers console
[Meta For Developers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nA2U8.png)

Comment: Message templates exist on the business account (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/whats-app-business-account/), not the individual phone numbers owned by that business (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/whats-app-business-account/phone_numbers/).

Comment: So you mean to say That I need to use my business id instead of   my phone number right??